# What is a Dependency Property and when is it used?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is a dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617312/what-is-a-dependency-property)

I have been browsing through the net to find the definition of a dependency prop, but cannot find the simplest def for this. Can anyone help me with an example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There have already been a number of discussions here itself regarding this.Please go through some.

[What is a dependency property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/617312/217880)

[What is the Dependency property in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3977378/217880)

[Dependency Property In WPF/SilverLight](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2424526/217880)

[How is dependency property implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/880950/217880)

[What is the difference between Property and Dependency Property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3674453/217880)

[Dependency Property Uses in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1050050/217880)

Also google and you can find some awesome articles.

http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/06/22/overview-of-dependency-properties-in-wpf/

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-introduction-to-dependency-properties

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article961-wpf-tutorial--dependency-property-.aspx

Comment: biju, edda link is not what has been asked for. You have to explain chetta.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quote from the [WPF 4 Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672331195) book:

> WPF introduces a new type of property
>   called a dependency property that is
>   used throughout the platform to enable
>   styling, automatic data binding,
>   animation, and more. You might first
>   meet this concept with skepticism, as
>   it complicates the picture of .NET
>   types having simple fields,
>   properties, methods, and events. But
>   when you understand the problems that
>   dependency properties solve, you will
>   likely accept them as a welcome
>   addition.
>
> A dependency property depends on
>   multiple providers for determining its
>   value at any point in time. These
>   providers could be an animation
>   continuously changing its value, a
>   parent element whose property value
>   propagates down to its children, and
>   so on. Arguably the biggest feature of
>   a dependency property is its built-in
>   ability to provide change
>   notification.
>
> The motivation for adding such
>   intelligence to properties is to
>   enable rich functionality directly
>   from declarative markup. The key to
>   WPF’s declarative-friendly design is
>   its heavy use of properties. Button,
>   for example, has 111 public properties
>   (98 of which are inherited from
>   Control and its base classes)!
>   Properties can be easily set in XAML
>   (directly or by using a design tool)
>   without any procedural code. But
>   without the extra plumbing in
>   dependency properties, it would be
>   hard for the simple action of setting
>   properties to get the desired results
>   without the need to write additional
>   code.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys,this has opened the light to dependency properties and when to use them and for what.I now understand them enough to work with them.